# x86 addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

I am very confused regarding the indirect addressing mode for this instruction:

```
and $0x0000FF00, 4(%esp)
```

If this is the current top of stack:

```
0xBF8DB0B8: 0xDEADBEEF <--- ESP + 4
0xBF8DB0B4: 0xDEADBEEF <--- ESP
```

and this is the content of memory at `0xDEADBEEF`:

```
0xDEADBEEF: 0x1234ABCD
```

Which of the following will be performed?

1. `AND 0x0000FF00, 0xDEADBEEF` with result: `0x0000BE00` stored in `0xBF8DB0B8`.
2. `AND 0x0000FF00, 0x1234ABCD`, with result: `0x0000AB00` stored in `0x0000AB00`.
3. `AND 0x0000FF00, 0xDEADBEF3`. with result: `0x0000BE00` stored in `0xDEADBEF3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND 0x0000FF00, 0xDEADBEEF` with result: `0x0000BE00` stored in `0xBF8DB0B8`:

Since `%esp` contains the address `0xBF8DB0B4`, `4(%esp)` is the address `0xBF8DB0B8` and `0xDEADBEEF` is what in that address.